# Having trouble understanding the salesforce REST API in PHP

Tags: php, rest, salesforce

Salesforce doesn't have (or appear to have) any tutorials that deal with using their REST api with PHP. If anyone knows about a good tutorial to learn it or a link to put turn me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check This link
http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2010/10/how-to-use-the-new-salesforce-rest-api-from-php.html Hope this will help You

Answer (score 2):

There's also this DeveloperForce Cookbook Recipe that shows how to call the REST API from PHP - http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php

Answer (score 1):

While not PHP specific, I've the [Apigee developer console](http://app.apigee.com/console/salesforce) useful for exploring the REST api.